# With PyGTK, how can I get the path name and not the uri for a drag and drop event?

Tags: linux, drag-and-drop, pygtk

I have developed an application under Ubuntu using PyGTK that allows a user to drag a file into a Label widget.  This is Python 2.7.  The applicable code is as follows:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

w = gtk.Window()
w.drag_set_set(0, [], 0)
w.connect('drag_motion', motion_cb)
w.connect('drag_drop', drop_cb)
w.connect('drag_data_received', got_data_cb)
w.connect('destroy', lambda w: gtk_main_quit())

l = gtk.Label()
l.set_text('Drag File Here')
w.add(l)
w.show_all()
gtk.main()

def motion_cb(wid, context, x, y, time):
    context.drag_status(gtk.gdk.ACTION_COPY, time)
    return True

def drop_cb(wid, context, x, y, time):
    wid.drag_get_dta(context, context.targets[-1], time)
    return True

def got_data_cb(wid, context, x, y, data, info, time):
    # the following line returns a URI?  I want the absolute file path
    print data.get_text()
```

So the `got_data_cb` function has a `gtk.SelectionData` item.  When I call `get_text()` it gives me a URI.  From Python 2.6 on, there is also a `get_uris()` function I spy as well.  How do I get the absolute file path returned instead of this uri?  My goal is to run an external program using the file selected by the user as a command line argument to the program (I already have this part working except that I need to pass the correct path for the file selected by the user).

Comment: You are right with using ``urlparse`` to extract the actual file system path. For any further information to get from the path, you should use [``os.path.basename``](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) and [``os.path.dirname``](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) (and possibly others from os.path). You might want to split your input on ``'\n'`` beforehands, to ensure that you process each uri on its own, if multiple uris are present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I see I can take the extra step to do like

```
my_path = urlparse.urlparse(data.get_text()).path
```

This will give me the full directory path including the file. Then I can do

```
base_directory = my_path.rsplit('/', 1)[0]
selected_file = my_path.rsplit('/', 1)[1].rstrip('\n')
```